# Get data from indexedDB using dexie and angular

Tags: angular, angular10, dexie

I'm using Dexie indexedDB. I can able to insert my data array to indexedDb but I cannot retrieve my data from indexedDB. Below is the code which I tried.

**Making DB**

```
makeDatabase() {
   this.db = new Dexie('CartDB');
   this.db.version(1).stores({
      CartList: '++Id,List'
   });
}
```

**Adding to index**

```
 addRow() {
   this.db.CartList.add({
    List: this.items
   });
 }
```

**Getting Data**

```
loadRows() {
   this.db.table("CartList").get().then(p => this.items = p);
}
```

This is how my data is stored in indexedDB.

[indexedDB Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFHlT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Id of the object to get

https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.get()

I see you are using auto-incremented primary key "Id". Is this your intention? If so, you'd need to store the Id that Table.add() returned and use it as the argument to Table.get(). You can also choose to specify an explicit id when you call Table.add() by adding the property Id to the object you are storing. In that case you might also consider using Table.put() instead, as it would accept overwriting an existing id whilst Table.add() will fail if there is already an object with the same id.